# OpenERP - redirected to "Create a New Database" page when accessing Odoo application

Tags: postgresql, odoo

When I try to access my Odoo 8 application I am redirected to Database Management menu and page "Create a New Database". However, there is a database in the system, I can see it through pgAdmin fine, and it worked all the time until now. As far as I know I have not changed anything.

How I can make Odoo 8 connecting to already present database again as it did before?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

You should also check the ownership of the database. If you restore it from psql, make sure you set the owner to your openerp user.

`ALTER DATABASE your_db OWNER TO your_openerp_user`

DB user & password are either specified from the CLI, i.e.

`openerp-server --db_user=openerp --db_password=openerp`

or they are specified in the configuration file usually located in :

`/etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf`

Comment: Thanks zee! Ownership was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

For that we must enter the administrator OpenERP database, one of the facilities provided to us in that menu is to restore the database from a backup, another option is to create a new database. A look created the database on the homepage of OpenERP can select the database with which we work and then insert the username and password.

Comment: Yes, but I had the prompt after the database was created and I had already installed modules. I guess I missed the step to set the admin password after the database was created.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I have backed up main database then restored it to a new database called TestA. When I opened Odoo web site, it picked up TestA database. Then I clicked on "Back to Login" option at the top right corner of the page and after that I was offered to chose between the two databases during login. I selected the main one and Odoo loaded successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue. I kept getting redirected to the login page even though the database was already created. What I did was change the admin password in the database using pgAdmin. At the page where the database creation is on there is a login option.

It's under the res_user table I just did this. After that I logged in I wasn't prompted with the database again.

```
Update res_user
Set password = 'your_password'
Where login = 'admin'
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I have tried your suggestion but I still got redirected to "Create a New Database" page.

Comment: How are you starting the Odoo server? Are using a configuration file or command line arguments? Also, did you install Odoo on Windows or Linux platform? I'm pretty new to this and been having some issues as well.

Comment: I am starting the server from command line, so that works nicely. My Odoo is on Ubuntu. I wonder where is the connecting database name stored so server knows to which database to connect.