# Can't start Odoo the first time if "Load demonstration" data is checked

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I just downloaded Odoo, installed dependencies and configured my IDE. After starting Odoo and being prompted to create my database and choose password it fails with the following error:

```
ParseError: "MissingError
One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing." while parsing /path/to/odoo/openerp/addons/base/base_data.xml:4, near
<record id="view_menu" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">ir.ui.menu.tree</field>
            <field name="model">ir.ui.menu</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Menu" toolbar="1">
                    <field icon="icon" name="name"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
            <field name="field_parent">child_id</field>
        </record>
```

I've tried dropping the database several times to no avail.

The current stacktrace:

```
2015-06-21 04:55:00,293 16487 INFO odoo-test werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2015 04:55:00] "GET /web/login?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8069%2Fweb%3Fdb%3Dodoo-test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2015-06-21 04:55:00,303 16487 ERROR odoo-test werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 285, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1281, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1255, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 588, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1427, in dispatch
    response = self.get_response(httprequest, result, explicit_session)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1362, in get_response
    result = request.registry['ir.http']._handle_exception(e)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 146, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 659, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1359, in get_response
    result.flatten()
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1232, in flatten
    self.response.append(self.render())
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1226, in render
    context=request.context)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1029, in render
    return self.pool[engine].render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, qcontext, loader=loader, context=context)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 261, in render
    return self.render_node(self.get_template(id_or_xml_id, qwebcontext), qwebcontext)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 192, in get_template
    raise_qweb_exception(QWebTemplateNotFound, message="Loader could not find template %r" % name, template=origin_template)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 190, in get_template
    xml_doc = qwebcontext.loader(name)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1027, in loader
    return self.read_template(cr, uid, name, context=context)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in read_template

  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 122, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 857, in read_template
    view_id = self.pool['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_id(cr, uid, xml_id, raise_if_not_found=True)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 944, in xmlid_to_res_id
    return self.xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(cr, uid, xmlid, raise_if_not_found)[1]
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 936, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(cr, uid, xmlid)[1:3]
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup

  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 74, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/proj/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 926, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in the system: web.login
```

Comment: Next error will be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857804/openerp-redirected-to-create-a-new-database-page-when-accessing-odoo-applica

Comment: You are missing series of "linux" dependency that openerp has.  Unfortunately it is not easy to figure out. In my case it was series of image processing libraries.. such as libjpeg.  You should see some error on console.  Please add that to question.

Answer (score 1):

In my case error was resolved with following steps.

First install series of missing dependencies

From my log, the following are installed for odoo. You can probably reduce the list by trial and error.

```
comerr-dev
gyp
javascript-common
krb5-multidev
libc-ares2
libc-ares-dev
libexpat1-dev
libffi-dev
libfreetype6-dev
libgssrpc4
libjpeg8-dev
libjpeg-dev
libjpeg-turbo8-dev
libjs-node-uuid
libkadm5clnt-mit9
libkadm5srv-mit9
libkdb5-7
libldap2-dev
libpng12-dev
libpq-dev
libpython2.7-dev
libpython-dev
libsasl2-dev
libssl-dev
libssl-doc
libv8-3.14.5
libv8-3.14-dev
libxml2-dev
libxslt1-dev
node-abbrev
node-ansi
node-archy
node-async
node-block-stream
node-combined-stream
node-cookie-jar
node-delayed-stream
node-forever-agent
node-form-data
node-fstream
node-fstream-ignore
node-github-url-from-git
node-glob
node-graceful-fs
node-gyp
node-inherits
node-ini
nodejs
nodejs-dev
node-json-stringify-safe
node-lockfile
node-lru-cache
node-mime
node-minimatch
node-mkdirp
node-mute-stream
node-node-uuid
node-nopt
node-normalize-package-data
node-npmlog
node-once
node-osenv
node-qs
node-read
node-read-package-json
node-request
node-retry
node-rimraf
node-semver
node-sha
node-sigmund
node-slide
node-tar
node-tunnel-agent
node-which
npm
postgresql-server-dev-9.3
python2.7-dev
python-dev
zlib1g-dev
```

Next was error coming from PIL.

I removed it and installed again :  See [Installing PIL with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip)

Comment: Thanks Jayan! I'm trying to install all of them now. Is there a comprehensive doc on odoo dependencies?

Comment: Tried installing those dependencies to no avail. I  just found out that the problem happens if I check `Load demonstration data:` when creating my DB..

Comment: Are you trying from install from "source code" ?  There is a docker version for playing around with product.  In any case, please update question with latest stack trace from console.

Comment: Posted the stacktrace! I'll checkout the docker version too.

Comment: Jayan, why did you think PIL might be the problem?

Comment: I had another exception after this. (some import related.).. I am not python expert; took the PIL help from other question (linked) and applied.

Answer (score 0):

First Install

- libjpeg-dev
- libfreetype6-dev
- zlib1g-dev

Uninstalling python-pil

- sudo apt-get purge python-pil

Installing pillow

- pip install pillow

these steps should resolved the problem. I hope help you, ^^

for more information see this link:

[[BUG] DB Creation :: ?Missing Dependency?](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/952)

[Odoo new dependency to Pillow](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/master/setup.py#L170)